# how to read argparser values from a config file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse

I have a lot of arguments for my script. And along with the argparser, I want users to also have the option to specify those arguments via a config file.

```
parser.add_argument('-a','--config_file_name' ...required=False)
parser.add_argument('-b' ...required=True)
parser.add_argument('-c' ...required=False)
....
```

At this point I just need the logic to implement the following:

- Either the users can type in all the arguments in the command line or
- They can type in the first argument, specify the file name and the code fills in/overwrites all the remaining optional arguments from the config file.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `ipython` reads the config file(s), and then populates a parser from those values.  Without digging into the code, the easiest way to get a sense of what it's doing is to compare the config file with the `--help-all`.

Comment: If the values from the config source are in a dictionary, then `.update(vars(args))`, can be used to over write them with `argparse` values. You'll need to use `SUPPRESS` to keep defaults out of the `args` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is up to argparse to handle.
Argparse simple needs to check if the argument for the config file is there and pass it on to your program.

You need to handle this in your program, which would mean doing something like:

```
...
arguments=parser.parse_args()
if len(arguments.config_file_name):
    f=fopen(arguments.config_file_name,'rb')
    conf_settings = f.read()
    for line in conf_settings:
        #parse your config format here.
```

this way, if the config_file_name is set, you will overwrite any possible given arguments, and if not, the program will be executed with the arguments specified by the user.

for example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("a")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.a:
    #We're getting config from config file here...
else:
    #We're getting config from the command line arguments
#Now we can call all functions with correct configuration applied.
```

Comment: how can i set the value of arguments since i believe the above code would go before the argparse code. I would be referencing something even before it is defined right?

Comment: You are storing your configuration/settings in variables, no? 

So basically you want a single flow that calls something like: `args = parser.parse_args()` and afterwards, tests if the `args.config_file_name` has a value.

If it does have a value, you must attempt to read the file, and write your own handler to set the settings from the file rather than obtain them from argparse.

Comment: so what you mean is check the config file first, if the file has the argument values, use it. If it does not, then check the command line arguments for values?

Comment: thanks...it is kinda clear now. I will have to implement a logic where i have list of all my arguments that i am expecting...so the text file does not give me surprises

Comment: Well, you could simply implement the entire argparse logic as it would exist without using a config file.

Then you simply add the argument to argparse for the config file, and in your python code, you check if this new argument is set, and if so, you run through your implementation of parsing the config file. (so the config-file logic will only be executed if the config-file argument is set, otherwise you simply execute the argparse logic and ignore the empty config-file argument :-) )

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is correct. But what if in the config file i get `z=something` and `z` is not a valid argument at all. Won't i need a list of arguments to check if the config file values are even valid or not? Am I considering that part correctly?

Comment: You're very close! But I think you need to understand that parsing the configuration from a file is a whole other world, and isn't simply a tweak in your argparse code. Have a look at [this, to make your life a lot easier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Comment: So basically, the `if ... else` in the example above should determine if you are going to create a ConfigParser object for the specified file, or you're just gonna assign all your configuration options from the values obtained through `parse_args()`.

Comment: As for inexistent values, they shouldn't matter. If you never assign the value to a variable, it will never be used.

Comment: From the docs i linked above: `print config.get('Section1', 'foo', 0)` ==> If you never request 'foo' from the config file, it simply won't matter it's there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is with [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) command line utility. This wouldn't give you exactly the command line interface that you describe, but would achieve the same effect.

`xargs` will run a command with arguments that it has read from standard input. If you pipe your arguments from the config file into `xargs` then your python program will be called with the arguments stored in the file. For example:

config.txt

```
-a -b --input "/some/file/path" --output "/another"
```

You could then use these arguments to your program like so

```
xargs ./my-prog.py --optional-arg < config.txt
```

because of the way that argparse works, it will take the value of the last argument if duplicates are found. Thus, if you have duplicate arguments, the ones from the config file will be chosen.